# How do I get the last value only from WHILE loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I just want the last value to be printed, but it is printing all of them:

```
<?php if (get_field('share_sentiment')):?>
<?php while (has_sub_field('share_sentiment')):?>
  <?php if (get_sub_field('share_medium')):?>
    <?php $kid = 0; ?>
    <?php while (has_sub_field('share_medium')):?>
      <?php
        $negative += get_sub_field('medium_negative');
        $positive += get_sub_field('medium_positive');
        $totalMinus = ($positive - $negative) / ($positive + $negative);
        $rounded = round($totalMinus, 3);
        print_r($rounded);
        ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
     <?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This is basic programmic logics, Even if you don't understand it you can find out by just trying.. I doubt you understand any programming when i look at this code.. Please search the php documentation first.

Comment: Why several opening and closing of php tags when no html is included.?

Comment: Oh my $DEITY, don't write your code like that.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Personally, I like it better this way in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `print_r($rounded);` after the loop. And `$rounded = round($totalMinus, 3);` too, I guess.

Comment: @HiroHito : Update with the code that you've tried.

Comment: how can i print the second last value?

Comment: @HiroHito : save to `$rounded[]` in `while` and then print as `$rounded[count($rounded) - 2]`

Comment: how do i save it to $rounded[]? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Instead of `$rounded` use `$rounded[]`. (It will push values to the `$rounded` array).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    echo $variable;
instead of print_r since the language used is php?

Comment: print_r is an actual PHP function which works quite differently from echo.